# Unable to copy file from external storage to data directory in Android 9

Tags: android

I am using this method to copy database file from external storage to data directory of my app. This method work fine on Android 8.0 and below, but not on Android 9.

```
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data  = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String  currentDBPath= "//data//" + "com.mypackage"
                    + "//databases//" + "dictionary";
            String backupDBPath  = "/MyApp/dictionary";
            File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File currentDB  = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Imported successfully",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

The "Imported successfully" toast is displayed but the file did not copy. The app do not crash and nothing show on logcat as well.

Comment: `new File(data, currentDBPath)` does not look correct with `String  currentDBPath= "//data//" + "com.mypackage"
                    + "//databases//" + "dictionary";`. Try debugging to see which path you get as result here

Comment: Please ignore the typo. I want to copy file from `"/MyApp/dictionary"` to `"//data//" + "com.mypackage" + "//databases//" + "dictionary"`.

Comment: I didn't see the typo, post your actual code, and  `Try debugging to see which path you get as result here`

Comment: What do you mean by actual code? Here are the code responsible to copy the file. The code is working fine on Android 8.0 and below. It only have problem on Android 9.

Comment: you said that you have some typo. That's why I asked for actual code (if you have fixed that typo), but most important is that you `Try debugging to see which path you get as result here`

Comment: Sorry, do you mind to teach me how to debug to see the path?

Comment: You need around 15 seconds searching in google to find how to do that. It even took me more time to write this comment

Answer (score 1):

**Since Android 7.0**, you need to use `FileProvider` in order to access to files in directories.
Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) and see [this example](https://medium.com/@ali.dev/open-a-file-in-another-app-with-android-fileprovider-for-android-7-42c9abb198c1).